# "No such network" error when trying to re-use Testcontainers rules with network from abstract class

Tags: testcontainers

Suppose I have an abstract class called `AbstractTestWithNetwork`:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public abstract class AbstractTestWithNetwork {

    @ClassRule
    public static Network network = Network.newNetwork();

    @ClassRule
    public static GenericContainer etcd = new GenericContainer<>("alpine:3.6")
            .withNetwork(network);
}
```

I would like to simply re-use it to have the same container in several classes by extending it:

```
public class FirstTestClass extends AbstractTestWithNetwork {
    @Test
    public void emptyMethod() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("An empty test method");
    }
}
```

There is also a `SecondTestClass` with the same content.

I can run each class separately from IDE and they will pass. But when I run `gradle test` or choose the whole package with test classes from IDE, only the 1st test class passes. For the second I get:

```
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
Caused by:
org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception
Caused by:
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
Caused by:
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
Caused by:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by:com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.NotFoundException: {"message":"No such network: a48cf082ab42a55c843e9963c3938f44dd93cceae09e1724d4fefd5b45f235f1"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the implementation and spotted [a bug in Networks' implementation](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/469).

In TestContainers <= 1.4.2, an instance of Network is not reusable, i.e. can't be used with @ClassRule.

But I have good news for you - **there is a simple workaround until it's fixed**: just remove @ClassRule from "network" field.